# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$ without using trigonometric substitutions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

How can I solve the integral

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$ without using any trigonometric substitution? I know that $$\frac{d}{dx} \text{arccosh} (x)=±\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Does the fundamental theorem of calculus apply? If so, I could conclude, for $x>0$, the integral as $$\text{arccosh}(x)+C$$

Comment: Yes, but this isn't "solving the integral" so much as it is verifying a solution.

Comment: Looking at [the WA solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+int+%281%2Fsqrt%28x^2-1%29%29+dx,+arccosh%28x%29) I see a different sign for $x < -1$ (third plot), so it might need a deeper look at the definitions.

Comment: Of course, this antiderivative can be derived by applying the reverse substitution $x = \cosh u$, $dx = \sinh u$, which gives $\int \,du$, but at least from a complex point of view this *is* trigonometric. One can obscure this fact by instead working with the exponential form of these functions and substitute $x = \tfrac{1}{2}(e^u - e^{-u})$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why you won't do a trigonometric sub, (put $x=\sec \theta$) , but anyway, this integral can be written as:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$ 
Substitute $1-\frac{1}{x^2}=t^2$,

You get $$\frac{2}{x^3}dx=2tdt$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{x}.\frac{1}{x^2}=tdt$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{x}.(t^2-1)=-tdt$$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{-tdt}{t^2-1}$$
Now, put everything back in the integral to get:
$$\int \frac{-dt}{t^2-1}$$
Which may be done by partial fractions or by splitting the numerator as $\frac{1}{2} (t+1-(t-1))$

Answer (score 1):

With $y= \sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $y\ dy=x\ dx$
\begin{align}
\int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx
=& \int \frac{dx}y= \int \frac{(1+\frac xy)dx}{x+y}
=\int \frac{dx+dy}{x+y}\\
=&\ \ln|x+y|=\ln \left|x+\overset{}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\right|+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Applying the rationalizing [First Euler Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution#Euler%27s_first_substitution), $$\sqrt{x^2 - 1} = -x + t, \qquad dx = \frac{t^2 + 1}{2 t} \,dt,$$ and simplifying leaves
$$\int \frac{dt}{t} = \log |t| + C = \log \left\vert\sqrt{x^2 - 1} + x\right\vert + C = \operatorname{arcosh} x + C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x^2-1=u^2$ thus $dx=\frac{udu}{x}$ but $ x=\sqrt{u^2+1}$ thus integral becomes after simplification $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}du=ln(u+\sqrt{u^2+1^2})+C$$

Comment: So, you know $\int\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}$ but not $\int\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}$

Comment: This begs the question in a way, as the latter integral is apparently no easier to handle without trigonometric substitution than the former.

Comment: Yes its given in my book under standard formulae why isnt this known??

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I think it is not given in some books. So in case anyone is wondering, it makes use of Euler substitution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: @ArchisWelankar how do you integrate that directly? In my book the result of the question that the OP asked is given directly, should I write it?

Comment: No op said he knows the result just wanted another way if there was for integration

Answer (score 0):

The function $\operatorname{arcosh}$ is only defined over $[1,\infty)$ where it satisfies $x=\cosh\operatorname{arcosh}x$, so
$$
1=\sinh\operatorname{arcosh}x\operatorname{arcosh}'x
$$
which means
$$
\operatorname{arcosh}'x=\frac{1}{\sin\operatorname{arcosh}x}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$
for $x>1$ (it is not differentiable at $1$).

Thus the most general antiderivative of your function is
$$
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{arcosh}x+c_+ & \text{for $x>1$} \\[6px]
-\operatorname{arcosh}(-x)+c_- & \text{for $x<-1$}
\end{cases}
$$
where $c_+$ and $c_-$ are arbitrary constants.

There's no need to do substitutions, trigonometric or not, if you already know about that function.